# meaning of fn() in the socket.io chat sample code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand a code from [socket.io/examples/chat/app.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/app.js).
I am not able to explain what the **`fn()`** calls mean in the lines 71 and 73.
I guess it is a callback function but where is its definition?
Is it a short invocation of another function from `app.js` ?...
Is it a call of a prototype function of the socket object?

The fragment is (lines 69-78):

```
[...]
    socket.on('nickname', function (nick, fn) {
        if (nicknames[nick]) {
          fn(true);
        } else {
          fn(false);
          nicknames[nick] = socket.nickname = nick;
          socket.broadcast.emit('announcement', nick + ' connected');
          io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
        }
    });
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn` is passed in as an argument to the callback function, right here:

```
socket.on('nickname', function (nick, fn) {
                                      ^^
```

Since JavaScript functions are objects, they can stored in variables — and passed as arguments into other functions.

The *use* of the callback function in this particular case is duscussed in the “Getting acknowledgements” section of the Socket.IO docs — calling it with some data sends a message *back to the client* as a response to that message.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that but how to find out what the actual body of that function is (I mean of fn)? A client sends 'nickname' message. Upon that function(nick, fn) is called back. But, again, what function is passed as fn? ...

Comment: Ok @Sidnicious, I think I got it. In fact, it is explained in the **Sending and getting data (acknowledgements).** section on [link](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

Comment: @gvlak: The callback function is defined [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0339e745fd75857b844f46368cc6d85aef295146/lib/namespace.js#L269), in namespace.js.

Answer (score 0):

fn is a reference to another function that is being called from within the on nickname event.

Comment: Thanks Jason. According to my understanding the `fn(true|false)` in my case corresponds to the `fn('woot');` in the example on page [socket.io#how-to-use](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

IN javascript, functions are treated as objects so they can pass as an argument with in a callback function.